# Check if the browser has the Silverlight plugin installed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, silverlight

I need to check if the client browser has a Silverlight plugin.
I prefer to check this from the code-behind (C# code), but if it's impossible,
using JavaScript is fine.  In the JavaScript case, I need to know how to access the JavaScript from the C# to check if the browser has the Silverlight plugin.

Comment: Do you need to know if the browser *does or doesn't* have Silverlight installed or just if it does?

Comment: I need to know just if it does, include the version number, thanks!

Comment: Two Jacobs?  This will be a bit confusing to follow...

Answer (score 1):

I googled for almost 4 seconds and found: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piotrp/archive/2008/05/07/determining-if-silverlight-is-installed-using-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to detect if the user has Silverlight installed, one thing you can do is create a Silverlight XAP and try to embed it in your web page.  Your Silverlight code could call a web service on your web server to let it know that Silverlight is installed and tell it which version.